# Flask not working with Virtualenv on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm having trouble starting a simple Python Flask app on my Raspberry Pi.

I have created a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper and it seems to be working. When I run `pip list` I get the following output.

```
argparse (1.2.1)
Flask (0.10.1)
gunicorn (18.0)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
MarkupSafe (0.21)
pip (1.5.4)
requests (2.2.1)
setuptools (2.2)
Werkzeug (0.9.4)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

As you can see

I have the following code in `simple.py`.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int("80"), debug=True)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello world!'
```

When I run `sudo python simple.py` on the Raspberry Pi I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

As far as I can see Flask is actually installed in my virtualenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're running it as `sudo`, the virtualenvs python and other variables are no longer used. You can easily prove this by running `sudo pip freeze` or `sudo pip list` and comparing the output with `pip freeze` or `list` respectively.

You have (at least) two options:

1. Run without `sudo`
2. Define which python you want to use. Virtualenvs are just wrappers for environments, so you can say `sudo /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python simply.py` and everything should work just fine.

I use the second one often (minus the `sudo`) when combining supervisord configurations with different python versions in virtualenvs, for instance when deploying flask applications. Works like a charm.

Comment: Great answer. Virtualenv sounds sometime magical, people are assuming, one has to call `activate` to make it working, but the secret truth is, it is enough to interpret your code using the python present in given virtualenv directory.